# Assigning variable coordinates - Python

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I have a list with indices as `K = [12,13,14,15,16,17]`.
I need to assign a coordinate to each index in `K` in the form of a variable `(x1,y1),(x2,y2)...`. 
Finally,  it should be like `(x1,y1)` for point `12`, `(x2,y2)` for point `13`etc.

Can someone please give me an idea for this?

Comment: Give an example of what you're trying to achieve, and some code you wrote.

Comment: What should `x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3` be? Is there a rule or something?

Comment: No, they are all variables. I'm just trying to find the Euclidean distance as a function of many variables.

Comment: So for `12`, what should `(x1,y1)` be in terms of numbers?

Comment: No, it should appear as symbols.

Answer (score -1):

Provided that you want to create a list of coordinates, you may just create a list that holds tuples.

Like so:

```
# initialize list of tuples with 10 list items to (0,0)
my_list = [(0,0) for x in range(0, 10)] 

# set the second list item to (3, 2)
my_list[1] = (3, 2)

# print the y coordinate of the second item
print(my_list[1][1])
```